# Infer Error: External Error: *** capture failed to execute: exited with code 65

Tags: ios, python-3.x, facebook, static-analysis, xcodebuild

I am running infer in one my hybrid iOS projects. Following is the command,

> infer --keep-going -o ./Infer --skip-analysis-in-path Pods -- xcodebuild clean build -workspace Codes/Project/Project.xcworkspace -scheme Main -configuration Release SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-Onone

Getting following error at the end of the build log.

```
External Error: *** capture failed to execute: exited with code 65
Error backtrace:
Raised at Stdlib.input_line.scan in file "stdlib.ml", line 449, characters 14-31
Called from Stdio__In_channel.input_line_exn in file "src/in_channel.ml" (inlined), line 68, characters 13-30
Called from IBase__Utils.with_channel_in in file "src/base/Utils.ml", line 260, characters 11-44
Re-raised at IBase__Die.raise_error.do_raise in file "src/base/Die.ml", line 26, characters 8-56
Called from Integration__Driver.capture in file "src/integration/Driver.ml", line 145, characters 6-36
Called from IBase__Utils.timeit in file "src/base/Utils.ml", line 429, characters 16-20
Called from IBase__ScubaLogging.execute_with_time_logging in file "src/base/ScubaLogging.ml", line 79, characters 29-44
Called from Backend__GCStats.log_f in file "src/backend/GCStats.ml", line 90, characters 10-14
Called from Dune__exe__Infer.run in file "src/infer.ml", line 20, characters 2-36
Called from IBase__Utils.timeit in file "src/base/Utils.ml", line 429, characters 16-20
Called from IBase__ScubaLogging.execute_with_time_logging in file "src/base/ScubaLogging.ml", line 79, characters 29-44
Called from Dune__exe__Infer.run in file "src/infer.ml", line 25, characters 22-94
```

**How to resolve it?**

```
infer version = 1.1.0_1
Xcode: 12.4
MacBook Pro, 2012 model
macOS: Catalina, 10.15.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps resolved my issue,

**Step 1:** Upgrade the infer version using following command,

```
brew upgrade infer #worked with version 1.1.0_1
```

**Step 2:** Create `compile_commands.json` file using the following command from the proper project directory,

```
xcodebuild -workspace Codes/Project/Project.xcworkspace -scheme Main -sdk iphoneos14.4 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO OTHER_CFLAGS="-DNS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(A)= -D_Nullable_result=_Nullable" | tee xcodebuild.log | /usr/local/bin/xcpretty -r json-compilation-database -o compile_commands.json
```

Here you have to change the workspace, scheme, sdk, xcpretty location values according to your own. if xcpretty is not installed you have to install it first using `sudo gem install xcpretty`.

**Step 3:** Use the created file in actual infer command, like,

```
infer run --keep-going --skip-analysis-in-path Pods --compilation-database-escaped compile_commands.json
```